# Uploading sitemap to Shopify root directory

Tags: shopify

In my shopify store, the sitemap is automatically generated and accessible on my website. But none of my images are ranking on google. So I need to submit my sitemap_images.xml file to root directory of Shopify.
The problem is there is no way to upload a file to root of Shopify from Admin as it has totally a different structure, its not like CPanel where I can directly upload any file.

Can anyone guide on how I can achieve this?

THanks in advance,
Diana